# What questions are not legal advice?

Tags: discussion, scope, legal-advice

How does the law stackexchange define which question is considered legal advice which question is not? If it refers to a very specific use case is it then considered legal advice?

Comment: This is a very broad question that has been dealt with extensively under [meta-tag:legal-advice].  I have closed as duplicate of one of just many questions that contain answers to this one.